# how to use json file in jenkins server?

Tags: json, jenkins, migration

I have make a job in jenkins in local and all work except sending an email at the end (but that is normal when I work in local). Now I need to migrate this job in my jenkins server.

During the build, I use a json file in the script shell "newman run ../../workflow-libs/testCollections" and I don't know how to use this (testCollection) file in my jenkins server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you are using `shell scripting`. So you can simply `cd <Path Here>` to change your directory. And in your case,

```
cd $WORKSPACE
newman run ../../workflow-libs/testCollections
```

You can simply do this. If you don't know how to create that file in `jenkins server`, Please login using `jenkins cli` and move or copy the file from local. Hope this helps.